# How do I reset the map of my minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

The map on my minecraft server has gotten really griefed and I would like to know how to reset it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recreate the map with the same seed:

- Type `/seed` on your console after hitting <kbd>T</kbd>
- If you are on single player, just feed the seed on the box:

[image]

- If multiplayer(your case) and using the vanilla server, on your [server.properties](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties) file add the following parameter on a newline: `level-seed=yourseedhere`